# How to put a variable into another variable array using python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make a bot right now using discord.py basically right now im testing out basic features right now. Basically I have a variable array with 3 compliments, then when the command /compliment is run on discord it picks a random number then prints that from the array (so everytime the compliment is difference.

However in the variable array I want to put another variable within one of the compliments, i thought you would use an f string but that just converts everything to a string. Below is the code im using

```
randomvariable = "hello"
randomvariablearray = "Good day","You are amazing","{myid} nice to meet you"
```

basically I want it to be that the 3rd sentence in that array would read Hello nice to meet you.

getting the string from the above array.

Comment: I recommend f-strings to put variables inside a string (python >= 3.6), and brackets `[ ]` for making arrays. For earlier versions of python, use `format()` or modulus `%` string formatting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.format()` is what your are looking for ?

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myid = 'Hello'
>>> randomvariablearray = "Good day","You are amazing","{} nice to meet you"
>>> print(randomvariablearray[2].format(myid))
Hello nice to meet you
>>>
```

Is this what you are looking for??
There is %s method as well, but this is the format method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use format function:

```
greetings = "Hello"
txt = "{myid} nice to meet you"
print(txt.format(myid = greetings))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare complement by:

- Putting your sentence part into a list;
- Rolling a random number;
- Creating your randomize compliment;

Code as example:

```
import numpy
# Put your sentence part in a list
randomvariablearray = ["Good day","You are amazing","{myid} nice to meet you"]
# Roll a number
number = np.random.randint(0, len(randomvariablearray))
# Create your randomize compliment
compliment = "hello, {0} !".format(randomvariablearray[number])
print(compliment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example command:

```py
import random

@bot.command()
async def compliment(ctx):
    rnd_compliment = "Hello"
    compliments = ["Good day!", "You're amazing :)", f"{rnd_compliment}, nice to meet you!"]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(compliments))
```

---

**References:**

- [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)
- [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)